# Why aren't we using the new stackexchange

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page

All my other accounts have newer stackexchange profiles and better websites. why are we still only using the older version of stackexchange?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6769/2451

Comment: Partly through requests like [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/can-we-have-a-font-which-harmonizes-better-with-mathjax), the site CSS update may take a bit longer than other sites. I'd rather they be thorough than rushed (but it is taking a longish time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile rollout is gradual across Stack Exchange IIRC

Comment: So, are there websites that aren't using the new system? please give me examples

Comment: @TanMath http://security.stackexchange.com/users/7497/manishearth for example. Why does it matter? It will be uniform across SE in some more time.